# How to compile and run a binary for openwrt on fedora?

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, fedora, openwrt

I use `gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram -Wall -Werror` to compile a program in fedora and then load the binary `myprogram`into the storage of a openwrt image that I'm running using qemu. Then in the openwrt image I try running the binary using `./myprogram`, I get `/bin/ash: ./myprogram: not found.` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a toolchain, to compile with the same libraries you have in your image (or compile it in QEMU if possible). Even if QEMU runs `x86_64` as I suspect is on your host, you should use the toolchain (for example your host and OpenWRT can use different libc / musl version - OpenWRT mostly comes with musl library)

Please refer to this [URL](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/using_the_sdk)
Here you will find the toolchain for the latest stable OpenWRT image [19.07.1].